# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) with dataTaskWithUrl

Tags: exception, swift, google-places-api

I'm using the google places api to search for nearby places. However, I only want places of specific types. The code (seen below) works when I specify just one type, but when I add a second my code runs and promptly give me a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) error on this line:

`session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data : NSData!, response : NSURLResponse!, error : NSError!) -> Void in`

I know the url is valid. I can plug it into the browser and see the json, so I don't understand what the problem is.

```
func search(location : CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius : Int, callback : (items : [Attraction]?, errorDescription : String?) -> Void) {
    var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.7873589,-122.408227&radius=4000&types=aquarium|art_gallery&key=YOURKEY"
    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data : NSData!, response : NSURLResponse!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            callback(items: nil, errorDescription: error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let statusCode = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if statusCode.statusCode != 200 {
                callback(items: nil, errorDescription: "Could not continue.  HTTP Status Code was \(statusCode)")
            }
        }

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
            callback(items: GooglePlaces.parseFromData(data), errorDescription: nil)
        })

    }).resume()
}


class func parseFromData(data : NSData) -> [Attraction] {
    var attractions = [Attraction]()

    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

    var results = json["results"] as? [NSDictionary]

    for result in results! {

        var placeId = result["place_id"] as String
        var image = result["icon"] as String
        var name = result["name"] as String
        var ratingString = ""
        var types = result["types"] as [String]
        println(types)

        if result["rating"] != nil {
            var rating = result["rating"] as Double
            ratingString = "\(rating)"
        }

        var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D!

        if let geometry = result["geometry"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let location = geometry["location"] as? NSDictionary {
                var lat = location["lat"] as CLLocationDegrees
                var long = location["lng"] as CLLocationDegrees
                coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

                var placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
                var attraction = Attraction(id: placeId, imageUrl: "image url", locationName: name, ratingAvg: "\(ratingString)", types: types, placemarker: placemark)

                attractions.append(attraction)
            }
        }
    }
    return attractions
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `var url = NSURL(string: urlString)` returns `nil` or not?

Comment: You're exactly right, but I cannot figure out why that's happening. When I plug my url into the browser it shows me the json it should be responding with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know the url is valid

The URL is *not* valid. You do *not* know what you think you know. Listen to the runtime. It knows more than you do.

Just try this code alone (in a playground, for instance):

```
var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.7873589,-122.408227&radius=4000&types=aquarium|art_gallery&key=YOURKEY"
let url = NSURL(string:urlString)
```

`url` is nil. And that's your problem. You cannot force-unwrap `nil`; you will crash if you do.

Once you acknowledge this, you can start to think about *why* the URL is not valid. (It's pretty obvious why that might be.) Learning to believe the compiler and the runtime is *key* to successful programming.

**HINT:** Form your URL like this and all is well:

```
let url2 = NSURL(scheme: "https", host: "maps.googleapis.com", path: "/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.7873589,-122.408227&radius=4000&types=aquarium|art_gallery&key=YOURKEY")
```

Why do you suppose that is? Look at the docs and see what this initializer does for you...

Comment: But I don't get why it's not valid when I can paste it into the browser and see the json I'm looking for, which is the exactly what I see when I enter a valid url as well.

Comment: I've given you a hint: see my revised answer.

Comment: I assume it's the pipe symbol, which would explain why this url string "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.7873589,-122.408227&radius=4000&types=aquarium&key=YOURKEY" works and the other does not.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate the solve and the resources.

Comment: You got it! Well done. You see, the browser is compensating for this mistake, but NSURL does not - unless you use an initializer that percent-encodes for you.

Comment: Down-vote for trickle-explanation, instead of full clear explanation

Comment: @BradThomas That's your privilege!

Comment: I have to agree with @BradThomas.  I can understand the desire to have OP find the answer himself--that will help him better grasp things at a more fundamental level.  But, ultimately, I feel StackOverflow is for answering questions, not giving hints to help the person asking find the answer.

Comment: I have also down-voted for the unclear explanation. If you want to explain it that way please write a tutorial on a blog and link.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding()`

```
var urlString = "http://example.com/?foo=bar|baz"
if var escapedURLString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    NSURL(string: escapedURLString)
}
```

Returns: `http://example.com/?foo=bar%7Cbaz`